# Using renderDataTable within renderUi in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, renderer

I'm experimenting a Shiny App to show dynamic contexts, but I cannot get `renderDataTable` working into a `renderUi` component.
Below two simple replicable tests: the first one is not working, the second one without `renderUi` works fine, of course.

What is the conceptually difference between this two, and why the first one cannot work in `Shiny`?

This one not works: note that the uiOutput `myTable`, contains two reactive component, a `selectInput` and a `renderDataTable`, but only the `selectInput` is rendered.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(
            fluidRow(h2("where is the table?")),
            uiOutput('myTable')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
            output$myTable <- renderUI({
                    fluidPage(
                            fluidRow(selectInput("test", "test", c(1,2,3))),
                            fluidRow(renderDataTable(iris))
                    )
            })
    }
))
```

This is fine, both `selectInput` and `renderDataTable` are rendered:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(
            fluidRow(h2("where is the table?")),
            fluidRow(selectInput("test", "test", c(1,2,3))),                
            fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable'))
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
            output$myTable = renderDataTable(iris)
    }
))
```

How to get the first scenario working?

Thanks.

EDITING after Yihui comment (thanks Yihui):

In `renderUi` has to be used some `ui` function, and not some render function:
changed the sample code in the correct way, the result does not change: still no data is shown.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
            uiOutput('myTable')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
            output$myTable <- renderUI({dataTableOutput(iris)
            })
    }
))
```

EDIT n.2

Just solved, got it working so:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(
            mainPanel(

                    uiOutput('myTable')
            )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
            output$myTable <- renderUI({
                    output$aa <- renderDataTable(iris)
                    dataTableOutput("aa")
            })
    }
))
```

I have to save the `renderTableOutput` in a output variable first, and then feeding it to `dataTableOutput`.

Thanks for pointing me to: [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/shiny-discuss/d9bf5ede-7403-4a42-9831-fa9e0c0974d3%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer)

Comment: Probably the same question as https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/shiny-discuss/d9bf5ede-7403-4a42-9831-fa9e0c0974d3%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Comment: thanks Yihui , I updated the question with the new code after reviewed your answer in https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/shiny-discuss/d9bf5ede-7403-4a42-9831-fa9e0c0974d3%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer. , but still no luck.

Comment: I can't understand why you want to "encapsulate" `renderDataTable` inside `renderUI`... If you have to create a "complex structure", can't you use `fluidPage`/`fluidRow`/`column`/`div`/... with one or more `*output`?

Comment: While the second edit might work, you are redefining output$aa every time output$myTable is refreshed, instead of letting the reactive model work. The more efficient way is as described in the answer by @Thomas

Answer (score 7):

It would be clearer if you split the part of `datatable` generation and `ui` generation :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = fluidPage(
            mainPanel(
                    uiOutput('myTable')
            )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
            output$aa <- renderDataTable({iris})
            output$myTable <- renderUI({
                    dataTableOutput("aa")
            })
    }
))
```