# if-statement in Shiny UI: evaluate simple numeric condition calculated in server

Tags: r, if-statement, user-interface, shiny, shinydashboard

In my way to learning Shiny rudiments, I do want to build a simple application that presents a `ui` with boxes with different background colours based on the value of a variable calculated in `server`.

I'm trying to use a classical `if-statement`, being `n_add_due_all` in `server`:

```
fluidRow(
  if(n_add_due_all > 0)
     {box(title = "to add", background = "red")} 
  else
     {box(title = "to add", background = "green")}
)
```

I've being trying to use `renderUI -> uiOutput` and `renderPrint -> textOutput` `server/ui` pairs, but I'm not able to get a numeric value suitable for the `n_add_due_all > 0` evaluation.

Please, is it doable? Is there any way of simply passing a numeric value from `server` to `ui`?

I found numerous related question and answers, but all of them seam much complex user-cases where some kind of interaction with user by selecting or entering values is required. In this case, the variable is completely calculated in `server` and should only be recalculated upon a page reload.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To increase the chances someone can help you, consider taking your program and making a version as small as possible that shows your issue. I imagine this particular question only needs a very simple `ui` and `server` to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(uiOutput("box"))
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  n_add_due_all <- -1

  output$box <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      if (n_add_due_all > 0) {
        shinydashboard::box(title = "to add", background = "red")
      } else {
        shinydashboard::box(title = "to add", background = "green")
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I should move the condition evaluation to `code`. But I'm facing now a new doubt: please, how could I show **mtcars** as generated with `output$mtcars <- renderDT(mtcars)` in any of the boxes generated by the nice code you proposed?

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813601/using-renderdatatable-within-renderui-in-shiny. I think it solves my doubt. I'll elaborate further and report back!